# Drupal 10 + Apache2 behind nginx reverse proxy setup with subdirectory

Tags: installation, proxies

I am trying to access my drupal 10 + apache2 installation through a subdirectory.
Currently I use nginx as a reverse proxy to access all my services (nextcloud, joplin, grafana) on my server. Therefore nginx handles the ssl certificate and redirects to the services with http://localhost:port.
With this I am able to access my services like this:
https://mydomain.com/nextcloud  -> nextcloud instance
https://mydomain.com/joplin     -> joplin instance
https://mydomain.com/grafana    -> grafana instance

Now I am trying to achieve the same with drupal. I want to use the subdirectory https://mydomain.com/homepage to access the drupal instance. With the currenct nginx settings like this:

```
    location ^~ /homepage/ {
            error_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress.log debug;
            proxy_redirect off;
            rewrite ^/homepage(.*) $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:85/;
```

I am able to access the welcome page. Although the page is missing all of the css styling. Additionally if I try to navigate to a different page I get an error 404 Not Found. Which makes sense, since I get directed to mydomain.com/user/login instead of mydoamin.com/homepage/user/login.
I am now stuck on how to resolve this. I was thinking of moving the drupal installation form the root directory "/" to the subdirectory "/homepage/", but changing the base_url was removed after drupal 7. I am not sure if I can somehow achieve this through a more advanced nginx configuration.

Any help on how to resolve my issue is appreciated. Thanks in advance!